# Running script on selected folder/drive using right click on windows explorer

Tags: powershell, windows-7

Environment: Windows 7

With the help of straight forward article from [Scott](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingPowerShellPromptHere.aspx), I am able to have "PowerShell Here" as the right click item of windows explorer.

Right clicking "PowerShell Here" opens a powershell command prompt with selected folder as the current working directory.

But I want little bit different which I am not able to do  - inplace of opening the powershell prompt, I want to run a powershell script taking argument as the selected drive/folder/filename!

So, I updated the following line of "powershellhere.inf" file,

```
;existing one
;HKCR,Drive\Shell\PowerShellHere\command,,,"""C:\WINDOWS\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe"" -NoExit ""cd '%1'"""

;updated one, added -Command <ScriptFile>
HKCR,Drive\Shell\PowerShellHere\command,,,"""C:\WINDOWS\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe"" -Command d:\temp.ps1 -NoExit ""cd '%1'"""
```

But when I right click and select the "PowerShell Here", it's not running the script in the selected drive/folder/file, it's running in C:\Windows\System32 folder.

Comment: Even though the directory says `1.0` you have at least 2.0 of powershell FYI. Use `Get-Host` to get the actual version of your PowerShell

Comment: Yes that's correct. I will edit the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string I believe you are looking for:

```
"""C:\WINDOWS\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe"" -NoExit -File ""C:\temp\test.ps1"" ""'%1'"""
```

`-NoExit` had to be before the `-File` else it was being picked up as an argument to the ps1 file. Also you need to put a full file path. I'm sure you could use environment variables. In my script i just had `Write-Host $args[0]` which output the path.

I was having an issue with the path being passed at first. I think the single quotes were not the ones I expected them to be inside the script. My script now changes directory successfully. Contents of test.ps1

```
$location = $args[0].Trim("'")
Write-Host "Path is valid = $(Test-Path $location)"
Set-Location $location
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `-File` instead of `-Command` and get rid of the `cd` stuff:

```
HKCR,Drive\Shell\PowerShellHere\command,,,"""C:\WINDOWS\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe"" -File d:\temp.ps1 -NoExit
```

`-Command` is for literal commands on the command line. You may also want to set the `-ExecutionPolicy` if you have an issue with that.

If you don't want the prompt to stick around after executing the script, get rid of `-NoExit`.

Comment: I tried -File also, but that did not help too. The -ExecutionPolicy also set correctly and seems no issue for that.

Comment: From my own testing I found other issues but first thing is that you are missing a closing quote on that string.